# Getting the Matched number of the two array

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have 2 arrays.

```
String[] arrFirst={"a","b","c","d","e"};
String[] arrSecond={"a","b","f","d","g"};
String[] arrThird={"a","f","g","h","e"};
```

I want the results like for `arrFirst` and `arrSecond` , the result is `3`

For `arrFirst` and `arrThird`, the result is `2`

All the code that I found are comparing two arrays and return whether they are example the same or not.

But what I want is how many are matched.

I can do the looping way.

But I think it will take too much time and I am wondering whether there is any faster way.

Thanks..

Comment: >>"I can do the looping way.............any faster way" -> looping is must in any way. All the answers below uses looping internally

Comment: what result do you expect if arrThird was {"a","f","g","e","h"}?

Comment: The earlier code will make sure that there is no duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) method.

```
    String[] arrFirst={"a","b","c","d","e"};
    String[] arrSecond={"a","b","f","d","g"};
    String[] arrThird={"a","f","g","h","e"};

    arrFirst.Intersect(arrSecond).Count(); // 3
    arrFirst.Intersect(arrThird).Count(); //2
```

Comment: +1, Intersect is the most appropriate answer here. Was posting it myself but Tilak beat me.

Comment: Yea, it works.. Thanks a lot. Just curious whether it will works if the array is not a `String` but an `Object`

Comment: Yes it should. Though i am not sure of logic  it uses for Equality (default Object.Equals, or will  just compare the reference in case of reference types). For value types, i am sure it will work.

Comment: If you need additional logic for comparing the array objects, `Intersect` provides an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408) with an `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` argument. Otherwise, in my [Zip example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11220689/650012) below, there is room for customized comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
arrFirst.Join(arrSecond,f=>f,s=>s,(f,s)=>f).count();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arrFirst.Zip(arrSecond, (a, b) => a.Equals(b)).Count(a => a);
```